# Creating a channel in Slack using Ruby

Tags: ruby, slack-api, slack

I'm trying to create a channel using the https://github.com/dblock/slack-ruby-client gem.

But it keeps on coming up with an error ":Name missing"

Can anyone give me a code snippet for creating channels with Slack please.

Dave

Comment: Provide the code you have written.

Answer (score 2):

Just looking at the source, you would do:

```
client = Slack::Web::Client.new(token: 'your_token')
client.channels_create(name: "my_channel_name")
```

Comment: Hi there Anthony, Thanks for your message.  Yes, I tried that. But I did find out why it wasn't working. I was using a slack_bot and I think they are not allowed to create channels.

Comment: You should ask the permission channels:write alongside the bot permission. The resulting user token can be used to create channels.