# How to gain user permission and create slack channel in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slack-api

I want to give the user updates from my app by creating a channel in his team. So I want to do 2 thing:

1. create a channel (e.g #coolapp) for my user (in his slack team)
2. send all update from my app to that coolapp channel

Thanks for stoping by.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a channel in Slack using Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37657390/creating-a-channel-in-slack-using-ruby)

Comment: @AlexandrT Is it possible to use my app token to create a channel for other team rather than mine?

Comment: probably not, you can't do anything to a team which you belong to, and that's determined by your api key.

Answer (score 1):

To create a channel you need (at a minimum) the `channels:write` scope (https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth-scopes) which I doubt your client will grant.  The best and easiest thing to do is to create a custom integration with the `incoming-webhook` scope which allows you to post messages to a channel selected by the user (not by you).  The customer can install your custom integration (app) using a [Slack Button](https://api.slack.com/docs/slack-button) and if you set it up correctly with an incoming-webhook; then when they install the app, they will select which channel your messages will post to.

This is all explained in [more detail here](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks).

Posting messages to the channel via the webhook is then really simple.  From the docs:

`curl -X POST \
--data-urlencode 'payload={"text":"This is a line of text.\nAnd this is another one."}' \
https://hooks.slack.com/services/T00000000/B00000000/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`